# cause effect graphing - creating simple graph

Tags: test-design

I need to draw an cause-effect-graph, I have read a lot about these graphs but still I am not able to draw one. I you could help me it would be perfect. Here is the description of program:

function `foo()` is checking the user inputted string and changing some chars,
1. if the char in string is `'&'` function will replace it with `'&amp;'`
2. if the char in string is `'<'` function will replace it with `'&lt;'`
3. if string does not contains any of these chars the string will be returned without changes.

Now I could not come with better solution as this:
Assumptions:

1. char is `'&'`
2. char is `'<'`
3. no char in string

Effects:

1. char changed to `'&amp;'`
2. char changed to `'&lt;'`
3. string unchanged

Explicit join:

7. 4 or 5

[image: cfg graph]

Could you guys confirm this solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution below. I think it's best to have only one level of 'effects'. Also, the string not replacing anything is the result of a cause that didn't happen, so I rendered it as such.

Additional thought: the 'mutually exclusive' lines are usually applied to causes, not effects (because they are determined by the graph).

- C1: string contains '&'.
- C2: string contains '<'.
- E1: string replacement for C1 occurs.
- E2: string returned as is.
- E3: string replacement for C2 occurs.

Note that E1 and E3 may happen together. E2 only happens if neither of C1 and C2 are true.

[image: Graph]

Another example similar to the approach of my solution [is found here](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/cause-and-effect-graph-test-case-writing-technique/).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, It may be correct, I will wait some time if someone has some different opinion, if not I will mark your answer correct

Comment: @nocturne I have added a different graph that I'm now completely convinced of :)